# Testing django geoodel with PointField results in TypeError

Tags: python, django, postgresql, gis, geodjango

I have the following model:

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geo_model

class UserAddress(geo_model.Model):
    user = geo_model.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_address"
    )
    coordinates = geo_model.PointField()
    address = geo_model.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = geo_model.CharField(max_length=20)
    country = geo_model.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now, I am trying to unit-test this model with pytest:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
class test_user_address():
    user_address = UserAddress(
        user=User(),
        address="my address",
        city="Oran",
        country="Algeria",
        coordinates=(7.15, 35.0)
    )
    user_address.save()
```

But, this is resulting in the following error:

```sh
TypeError: Cannot set SeekerAddress SpatialProxy (POINT) with value of type: <class 'tuple'>
```

How should I pass datatype in coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a temporary solution, I should have used `Point` instead of a `tuple`. I thought that `PointField` would accept a tuple and convert it to a `Point`.

Basically, here is what I did:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_user_address():
    user= User()
    user.save()
    user_address = UserAddress(
        user=user,
        address="my address",
        city="Oran",
        country="Algeria",
        coordinates=Point(7.15, 35.0)
    )
    user_address.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an instance of [`django.contrib.gis.geos Point`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#point).

So the correct code for your test is:

```
coordinates=Point(7.15, 35.0) # you can use tuple if you prefer but it's not mandatory
```

Comment: thank you I just found the Answer, I though that PointField would accept a tuple and convert it into a Point

Comment: You welcome, in fact your idea could be an interesting feature request.

Comment: Yes, I think it is more convenient if I get a tuple from my front-end and put it directly into my serializer to go into PointField. This is more direct and clear.